# When to use QMutex in C++ Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have 2 scenarios where I don't know whether I should use `QMutex` or not.
I have run the program without `QMutex` many times & it hasn't shown me any abnormal behaviour. I have skimmed down the code here for simplicity.
But still as a safe side I would like to know whether I should use `QMutex` or not?

**Scenario #1:**

```
 class A : QObject
 {
    Q_OBJECT

    private double **array;//it is initialised in the constructor & is 100x100

    slots:
          slot1(); //2 Qthreads are created in my main GUI thread along with 2 objects of class A, & by A aobj.movetothread();
          slot2(); //& connecting these 2 slots to started() SIGNAL of respective QThread's
                   //I have multi-threaded my application.
 }

 A::slot1()
 {
    double temp = array[i][j];
    //some operations on temp
 }

 A::slot2()
 {
    double temp = array[i][j];
    //some operations on temp
 }
```

NOTE: The contents of `array[][]` are not changed after initialisation. I am only *accessing* the information from it in the 2 *threads*. However sometimes the *same element* from `array` maybe accessed by both threads simultaneously!

**Scenario #2**

```
 A::slot1()
 {
    double temp = somefunc();
    array[0][j] = temp;
 }

 A::slot2()
 {
    double temp = somefunc();
    array[50][j] = temp;
 }
```

NOTE: In this case, the 2 *threads* modify elements from the same array, however they don't modify/access common elements i.e. *thread1* deals with say first *50 rows* while *thread2* deals with *next 50 rows*, however they don't even access rows of each other.

Comment: Are your two scenarios running simultaneously? none of them seems to need the mutex by itself, but if they are executing simultaneously, then you need to synchronize between scenario2 ans scnario1 - imagine that you access from first scenario some data, and second one writes data in the same row. you may end up reading a half of actual data and other half of renewed data, which can broke consistency (it depends on actual code, though, you need to decide yourself, is it ok or not)

Comment: no they are sepparate cases!
They do NOT happen simultaneously!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if those scenarios doesn't run together, you need no mutex. accessing the data for read from two of threads are ok, modifying different elements from the same array in two (or even more threads) are ok too. the cases where you need mutex is either when two thread modifies the *same* element from array, or if you modify *same* elements from one thread while reading them from another one